# C# SSIS Package User

Tags: c#, ssis, impersonation

I am trying to run an SSIS package from C# which I have working by itself. The problem I am having i that I want to have the user for the package set on the fly. I set up an impersonator class that seems to be working, yet the package is throwing errors when ran from IIS. However it does work when I run it from VS2010 debug.

```
   using (ImpersonatedUser iu = new ImpersonatedUser("username", "domain", "password"))
   {
        Application app = new Application();
        Package package = null;
        MyEventListener eventListener = new MyEventListener();

        app.PackagePassword = "packagepassword";
        package = app.LoadPackage(@"packagepath", null);

        Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult results = package.Execute(null, null, eventListener, null, null);
        if (results == Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure)
        {
            foreach (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsError local_DtsError in package.Errors)
            {
                lblErrorOutput.Text += "<br />Package Execution results: " + local_DtsError.Description.ToString();
                lblErrorOutput.Text += eventListener.output;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblErrorOutput.Text = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
            lblErrorOutput.Text += eventListener.output;
        }
    }
```

Here is the output when running from debug then when I run from IIS (on the same computer)

```
domain\user
Information: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost/SSIS.Pipeline : Validation phase is beginning.
Information: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost/SSIS.Pipeline : Validation phase is beginning.
Information: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost/SSIS.Pipeline : Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.
Information: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost/SSIS.Pipeline : Pre-Execute phase is beginning.
Information: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost/Source File [1] : The processing of file "filepathandname.csv" has started.
Information: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost/SSIS.Pipeline : Validation phase is beginning.
Information: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost/SSIS.Pipeline : Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.
Information: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost/SSIS.Pipeline : Pre-Execute phase is beginning.
Information: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost/Flat File Destination [16] : The processing of file "filepathandname.csv" has started.
```

then when through IIS

```
 domain\user
Information: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost/SSIS.Pipeline : Validation phase is beginning.
Information: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost/SSIS.Pipeline : Validation phase is beginning.
Error in: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package/Connection manager "SourceConnectionFlatFile" : The file name property is not valid. The file name is a device or contains invalid characters.
Information: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost/SSIS.Pipeline : Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.
Error in: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package/Connection manager "SourceConnectionFlatFile" : The file name property is not valid. The file name is a device or contains invalid characters.
Information: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost/SSIS.Pipeline : Pre-Execute phase is beginning.
Error in: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package/Connection manager "SourceConnectionFlatFile" : The file name property is not valid. The file name is a device or contains invalid characters.
Information: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost/SSIS.Pipeline : Execute phase is beginning.
Information: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost/Destination -  : The final commit for the data insertion in "component "Destination" (94)" has started.
Error in: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost/File System Task : An error occurred with the following error message: "Could not find file 'filepathandname.csv'.".
```

everything I see is leading me to believe that its permissions based and the user that is running the package doesnt have access to the file. When running through debug it works as it is running as me logged into the computer, however when run through IIS it is the DefaultAppPool running it.

The check I added "lblErrorOutput.Text = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;" is showing me the user I would expect. I can't quite figure out what is going on. Is the package execution ignoring the impersonated user? If so how do I get it to take.

Thanks

Comment: Does the account for DefaultAppPool have access to the file system? You aren't hitting a UNC are you?

Comment: it does not, and I want to avoid having to give permissions to it, which is why I am attempting to implement the impersonation. You mean network resource by UNC? (I hadn't heard UNC before and I just wikid it...) if so yes it is a network resource.

Comment: do you have a service account user / password setup where you can alter it based on \\DomainUser\Password..?  this is a permissions issue.. my question is .. are you sure you want to impersonate the user..?

Comment: UNC = Universal Naming Convention aka `\\sever\share\x` Reason I ask is the share may or may not be valid for everyone.

Comment: Yes I have a service account. I have tested with the service account and my account and neither have worked, though both impersonate fine based on WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; inside the using statement, and both have access to the share

Comment: Here is a good article that will show you what to set up in regards to setting up the Impersonate to run under Network Service read both articles this should help
http://dotnet.kapenilattex.com/?p=17 | [setting up Network Service](http://www.bluevisionsoftware.com/WebSite/TipsAndTricksDetails.aspx?Name=AspNetAccount) `also does the Package have a separate Password setup on it ..?` if so this could be what is causing your issue.. use that Packages Password and Network Service account name ..try that

Comment: Thanks for the article, it had the answers I was looking for. So it seems I'm stuck giving permissions to the network service since once it shoots off the SSIS package it executes under the helper process that always uses the AppPool Identity instead of the impersonated user. Not the answer I was hoping for, but I'm thankful to have an answer.